# sort files found by command 'find'

Tags: linux, bash, shell, find

My program takes a list of files and processes them according to the order in which the files are given. For instance:

```
$ ./myScript.sh --takeFiles a b c d e f g
```

Now, since I have to pass a considerable number of files, I use the `find` command and specify how to find the exact files I want:

```
sudo find . -path "./aFolder/*_parameterOne_*_*/*_parameterTwo_*_*/*_someCommonString_*" ! -name "*_aStringToExclude*" -exec ./myScript.py --takeFiles {} +
```

It works like a charm, except that I would my files to be passed to myScript.sh after being **sorted first** by "parameterTwo_**" (where in the star I have an integer) **and then** by "parameterTwo**_" where again the star stands for a numerical value.

Is it possible?

Comment: `find -whatever -print0 | sort -z -whatever | xargs -0 ./myScript.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The the parts before `parameterOne` and `parameterTwo` do not contain the character `_`, you can simply use `sort`:

```
find ... -print0 |
sort -z -t_ -k6n -k3n |
xargs -r0 ./myScript.py --takeFiles
```

**Update:** A more complex solution might look as follows. However, I think it would be easier to sort the pathnames in the Python script.

```
#! /bin/bash
find ... -print0 |
while IFS= read -r -d '' pathname; do
    [[ "$pathname" =~ "_parameterOne_"([0-9]+).*"_parameterTwo_"([0-9]+) ]] &&
    printf '%05d%05d %s\0' "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" "$pathname"
done |
sort -z |
while IFS= read -r -d '' pathname; do
    printf '%s\0' "${pathname#* }"
done |
xargs -r0 ./myScript.py --takeFiles
```

Comment: OK, I made sure parameterOne and ParameterTwo were between underscores and just localized on which underscore-separated field they were. Thanks!